# How can I add specific elements in an array using multiple parameters?

Tags: python, arrays, sum

I have an array of weather data with columns (day, month, year, rain, temp, etc.). The task is to sum the amount of rain falling each summer (each summer's total rain is to be plotted against its year).

To sum the required elements such that each year's summer elements are added together, I'm going to have to use a for loop (there are over 80 years, so manually finding the numbers of the entries is probably unfeasible for a sum(rainfall[summer][0:90]) repeated for all years). I've also made a list of the relevant years (but not filtered only the summer entries into these). I've unsuccessfully tried to make a loop that would sum elements in summer with the same year.
Looking for any advice on how I could try this. Thanks.

A sample of the data (for the first days of Jan 1942):

```
day, month, year, min_temp (C), max_temp (C), rainfall (mm), windspeed (knot)

1,1,1942,6.8,9.7,0.0,17.2 

2,1,1942,7.9,9.9,0.1,15.2

3,1,1942,8.9,11.2,1.5,14.0

4,1,1942,2.7,9.2,3.5,17.0

5,1,1942,-0.8,3.5,0.6,13.0

6,1,1942,0.7,5.1,0.0,9.7

7,1,1942,0.5,7.1,0.0,10.3
```

These were arranged using (eg for the day column):

```
day = day.astype(int)
```

I first gathered summer entries using:

```
summer = np.where((month == 6) | (month == 7) | (month == 8 ) )
```

where the first element is the data of 1/6/1942.
After this point, I had little success grouping summer entries into their years and only created a simple list of the relevant years using a simple for loop.

Just for reference, in similar tasks, I would have used compiled a dictionary and then used the keys and values as the datapoints for the plot.

Also, for reference, the first 90 entries (corresponding to the first summer) sum to:

```
sum(rainfall[summer][0:90])
```

which outputs the correct sum of the rain in the first summer group.

Frank Yellin (in the threads below) advised use of np.histogram to get around having to compute and save the sums of the summers' rainfalls, but I haven't had luck with that either ("weights must be the same shape as a" (a is summer, which I took to be the array the histogram would gather data from)). While it didn't work, it might be of use to see my line of thinking.

```
np.histogram(summer, bins = years, range = (1942, 2020) , weights = rainfall[summer])
```

I should say as well as that I'm quite new to using arrays for data manipulation, so any help is appreciated. As for a minimum reproducible example, I've included the most important parts of the code I have, but I'm still not sure what the correct approach for this should be (creating a dictionary as previously discussed, using a histogram as was suggested, etc.) , so I'm short on that end also. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include a snippet of your code, along with a small version of the data you're working with? That makes giving an answer much easier.

Comment: Updated to include some data and a little more code for clarity.

Comment: Your data is in a numpy away? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite have the precise code to do what you want, since I don't know your data structures, but I think you can achieve what you want with [np.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

- The `a` argument is the array of years, filtered to only show the
  summer months.
- The `weights` argument is the array of rain amount, again filtered.
- The `bins` argument will be a sorted list of all the years.

Comment: So, I could dodge having to sum and store the rain amounts for each summer by simply setting the histogram to include and therefore sum the rain in the period of the bin?

Comment: It ought to work according to the documentation.  I've done similar things in the past. Can you try it on a small sample?

Comment: I'm still confused on how to correlate the summers to each year so that each summer entry's rain? Do you have any advice on how I could write the histogram?

Comment: Let's suppose your years are 1940-1950 (inclusive).  Then the bins should be np.arange(1940, 1952).  You'll get as output an 11-element array.  The first element is 1940, the second element is 1941, ...  At least that's how I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

After days of banging my head on my table, I found a solution using what turned out to be a relatively simple method. I think I was overcomplicating the problem by trying to get out all parts of the answer in one step. Instead of going through the arrays to make a dictionary, I used a for loop to make lists for both the years and summed rainfalls of the summer array. I realised a shortcut that each year of summer occurred within 92 entries of the entire summer array (and discovered that slicing can be more complex than lone i's or integers).

```
rains = []

for i in range(0, 79, 1):
    y = sum(rainfall[summer][i*92:i*92 + 92])
    rains.append(y)
```

For the years necessary;

```
years = []
for i in range(1942, 2021, 1):
    years.append(i)
```

And then using plt.plot(years, rains) got me this beautiful graph:
[rainfall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBM7v.png)

Thanks to the other contributors for their help. I cannot describe my joy at seeing a fairly mundane graph.